dockerizing Laravel + vue. i am getting database conenction issue SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away
this is my docker.yml file
services:
  web:
    image: app-name:latest
    build:
      target: web
      context: .
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    ports:
      - 3307:3307
    expose:
      - "3307"
    cap_add:
      - SYS_NICE 
    command: --skip-grant-tables
    volumes:
      - ./cache/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./conf-mysql.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=chat

    restart: unless-stopped

volumes:
  dbdata:



this is my database file config in .env


DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=host.docker.internal
# DB_HOST=db
DB_PORT=3307
DB_DATABASE=chat
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=password


i have tried db as well host.docker.internal.  but unable to resolve this issue your text
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away
i want to connect of my docter app to database`your text``

Try

services:
  web:
    image: app-name:latest
    build:
      target: web
      context: .
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      my_network:
        ipv4_address: 172.18.0.11

  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    expose:
      - "3306"
    cap_add:
      - SYS_NICE 
    command: --skip-grant-tables
    volumes:
      - ./cache/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./conf-mysql.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=chat
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      my_network:
        ipv4_address: 172.18.0.10

networks:
  my_network:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.18.0.0/16

volumes:
  dbdata:

.env
DB_HOST=172.18.0.10
DB_PORT=3306


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Use localhost as DB Host.
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
# DB_HOST=db
DB_PORT=3307
DB_DATABASE=chat
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=password

check container-id
docker container ls 

only first 4 characters required.
check logs using this command. Eg.
docker log a1bcd


I see a couple of issues. When using docker, you should use the service name as the host. In your case, that would be 'db'. So in your .env file, use:
DB_HOST=db

You're exposing MySQL on port 3307, but the standard MySQL port is 3306. Change the MySQL port to 3306
db:
  ports:
    - 3306:3306
  expose:
    - "3306"

then in your .env file:
DB_PORT=3306


If you still have the error after trying these steps, share your custom MySQL configuration file.
